# In A Solution With Many Projects And App.config Files, Which Does ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Read?

Tags: c#, app-config, appsettings, configurationmanager

The full question is in the title really. But here is a little background. I have a solution with a dozen projects in. Up until now, there were only two `App.config` files and I could read from each without problem. But after importing the `NewtonSoft.Json` NuGet package, it added binding redirects into a new `App.config` file in every project. Now, I can no longer find my settings when using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` from various projects.

So, to repeat the question, *which project's `App.config` file is used when I use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` in any particular project?*

Comment: _"`Json.NewtonSoft`"_ - you have the name reversed, it's `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: _"it added binding redirects into a new App.config file in every project. Now, I can no longer find my settings "_ - that makes no sense: `<bindingRedirects>` are in an entirely separate `<configuration>` element - whenever VS makes changes to `app.config` or `web.config` it's always done a (relatively) good job of leaving the other content of `.config` files well-alone. I suspect something else is going on...

Comment: Also... isn't your project/solution under source-control? Why not just run a `diff` and/or undo/reverse the bindingRedirects and see if that fixes things for now?

Comment: **Finally**... `<bindingRedirects>` aren't necessary at all if you're using `<PackageReference>`... so why aren't you using `<PackageReference>`?

Comment: Thanks, corrected. I didn't add these binding redirects. I found my problem. I am stupid!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I *can* still read the settings when running the application. The problem that I had was because I was running within a unit test context, so I guess the configuration system was not running.